# how to make autocomplete search box in yii

Tags: search, yii, autocomplete

can anybody give tutorials about how to make autocomplete search box in yii?

I prefer to work with `CJuiAutoComplete`, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a wiki page to do that
[follow this wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/162/a-simple-action-for-cjuiautocomplete/)